# Collecting with casts and lambdas

Tags: java, lambda, casting, collectors

I am running into an issue in java 8 where it is not allowing me to collect objects when using a cast.

```
definitions.stream()
           .map(Definition.class::cast)
           .map((Definition definition) -> { 
               WonderfulDefinition wd = new WonderfulDefinition();
               wd.name(definition.getName());
               //etc
               return wd;
           }).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

And I am getting the compiler error:

> Error:(71, 23) java: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
>       equality constraints: java.util.List
>       lower bounds: java.lang.Object

Any help would be appreciated.

Updated:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List definitions = new ArrayList<>();
        definitions.add(new Definition());
        definitions.add(new Definition());

        List<WonderfulDefinition> list =
                definitions.stream()
                        .map(Definition.class::cast)
                        .map((Definition definition) -> {
                            WonderfulDefinition wd = new WonderfulDefinition();
                            wd.name(definition.getName());
                            //etc
                            return wd;
                        }).collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
class Definition {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void name(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
class WonderfulDefinition extends Definition {
}
```

Comment: What type contains your initial ``definitions`` list ?

Comment: Object unfortunately. It's coming from a 3rd party lib that returns definitions as List with no type. 

i.e.

dictionary.getDefinitions() returns just List

Comment: What type the List variable has? It probably marking that part, since there's no other mentions of lists.

Comment: Please update your question with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which reproduces the issue you're having. Here's an example where your code as-is appears to work: https://ideone.com/IPoexa

Comment: Hi Radiodef, I updated it. Due to list being just "List" (lib code can't change it) without a type specifier (object or otherwise) it is failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `List` is untyped. In this case, simply hint the compiler by performing a cast:

```
((List<Object>) definitions).stream()
      .map(Definition.class::cast)
      .map(definition -> {
          WonderfulDefinition wd = new WonderfulDefinition();
          wd.name(definition.getName());
          //etc
          return wd;
      }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

keep in mind that something like this is perfectly valid:

```
List definitions = Arrays.asList(new Definition());
List<Object> d = definitions;
```

Comment: @CoffeeIsProgramming I tested it using the provided example. Works fine